# A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)

Tags: appium, genymotion

A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Please let me know the cause and solution for the error. Its been bugging my head from 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Appium only supports one session at a time for a device.
Maybe you are trying to open a new session before closing the previous one?